# Javascript setInterval execute 1000000000 per second

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I want to use setInerval to make increment up to 1,000,000,000 per second .

```
 (function counterIt(starting,speedPerSecond){
    var speed=0;
    var intervalCount=1;
    if(speedPerSecond<100){
        extraSpeed=1;
        speed=1000/speedPerSecond;
    }else{
        extraSpeed=speedPerSecond/1000;
        speed=1;
        if(extraSpeed>1000){
            intervalCount=extraSpeed/1000;
            extraSpeed=extraSpeed/intervalCount;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML=starting;
    for(var interval=0;interval<intervalCount;interval++){
        setInterval(function(){
            for(var i=0;i<extraSpeed;i++){
                    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML=parseInt(document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML)+1;
            }
        },speed);
    }
 })(0,1000000);
```

What Im trying to do is .
interval time is only for 1 millisecond .
 and the other is loop.( many interval + loop )

Is there a limit for increment speed in browser ? 
or there is  best way to that?

Try  [**THIS FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/teorbc3e/1/)

Thank you.

Comment: The browser only draws 60 frames per second (at best), so you don't need to do that anyway.

Comment: `postMessage` [can be faster](http://dbaron.org/log/20100309-faster-timeouts), but I doubt that fast.

Comment: According to jsperf my server class machine can increment a number at 520 million ops (just that one line of code).  Doing anything more than that will slow things down considerably so I doubt you could do a billion of anything especially after adding in timer and DOM overhead.

Comment: The interval parameter has a resolution of milliseconds, but the minimum value is 5 ms in modern browsers, more in older browsers. As SLaks pointed out, there is no point in updating anything faster than the screen can show it. Also, updating an element in a loop is pointless, the browser won't show any change until you exit the function, so you can just set it to the last value (add `extraSpeed` to it) and skip the loop.

Comment: can you take look for this ,
I think the problem is with rendering  into screen
http://jsfiddle.net/teorbc3e/3/

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a limit for increment speed in browser ?

Yes. The [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#timers) says

> If *nesting level* is greater than 5, and *timeout* is less than 4, then increase *timeout* to 4.

That means that, after 5 calls to the handler, there is a minimum delay of 4 milliseconds.

Moreover, note that using `setInterval` with a small timeout ca be dangerous, because if the handler takes more time to run than the timeout, you may freeze the browser.

Instead, consider using `setTimeout` at the end of the handler.